# Roundabout square method of iterating in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, opencv

I'm processing some video in OpenCV which of course handles frames as two dimensional numpy arrays. I would like to iteratively search in an area around a specific pixel. Rather than iterating by column then row, I'd like to progress through values in a snaking square pattern. I'll try to illustrate below.

X is the pixel with which we start looking around.

```
000   100   110   111   111   111
0x0 > 0x0 > 0x0 > 0x0 > 0x1 > 0x1
000   000   000   000   000   001
```

As you can see it will continue snaking around the starting point until it reaches the column it started from. At the point it should extend left one more column and start moving upward in the array. This won't be an infinite iteration, but rather it will stop running when a certain number of corner values match a given value.

So far I've been able to iterate over the array however, I'm not sure how to tell it to stop at a certain point which is dynamic over the life of the iteration.

```py
def search_local_area(area, start_pt):
    """Search the area around the pixel identified as a 'good point' in a roundabout-square."""
    test = np.zeros_like(area)
    for row, _ in enumerate(area[..., start_pt]):
        for column, value in enumerate(area[start_pt, ...]):
            test[row, column] = value
```

The above code just copies values into a test array to show that it's iterating in the right direction.

Comment: Are you doing template matching? If so, you can accomplish this with numpy slices instead of having to determine a search pattern.

Comment: It's not really template matching. I'm comparing pixel values to a known average to determine where to draw a bounding box. Similar to background subtraction but in a specific area.

Comment: Okay. Is the search path direction important? Does it have to snake or is any path that yields a bounding box sufficient?

Comment: I just thought that searching in a snake pattern might be able to quickly find the corners of where the bounding box should go. Essentially I know what the value I'm looking for is. What I'm drawing the box around is the set of pixels which is NOT close to the value I know.